# Optionally call `skip` in a custom iterator `next()` function

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a custom iterator and I would like to optionally call `.skip(...)` in the custom `.next()` method. However, I get a type error because `Skip != Iterator`.

Sample code is as follows:

```
struct CrossingIter<'a, T> {
    index: usize,
    iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
}

impl<'a, T: Float> Iterator for CrossingIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);


    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, T)> {
        let iter = (&mut self.iter).enumerate();
         
        let iter = if self.index == 0 {
            self.index += 3;
            iter.skip(3)
        } else {
            iter
        }

        // lots of code here working with the new iterator        

        iter.next()
    }
}
```

The issue is that after calling `.skip(3)`, the type of `iter` has changed. One solution would be to duplicate the `// lots of code ...` in each branch of the `if` statement, but I'd rather not.

My question is: Is there a way to conditionally apply `skip(...)` to an iterator and continue working with it without duplicating a bunch of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) is designed to construct a new iterator, which is very useful in situations where you want your code to remain, at least on the surface, immutable. However, in your case, you want to advance *the existing* iterator while still leaving it valid.

There is [`advance_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.advance_by) which does what you want, but it's Nightly so it won't run on Stable Rust.

```
if self.index == 0 {
  self.index += 3;
  self.iter.advance_by(3);
}
```

We can abuse [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) to get what we want, but it's not very idiomatic.

```
if self.index == 0 {
  self.index += 3;
  self.iter.nth(2);
}
```

If I saw that code in production, I'd be quite puzzled.

The simplest and not terribly satisfying answer is to just reimplement `advance_by` as a helper function. [The source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#318-323) is available and pretty easy to adapt

```
fn my_advance_by(iter: &mut impl Iterator, n: usize) -> Result<(), usize> {
  for i in 0..n {
    iter.next().ok_or(i)?;
  }
  Ok(())
}
```

All this being said, if your use case is *actually* just to skip the first three elements, all you need is to start with the `skip` call and assume your iterator is always `Skip`

```
struct CrossingIter<'a, T> {
  index: usize,
  iter: std::iter::Skip<std::slice::Iter<'a, T>>,
}
```

Comment: To complicate matters slightly, I'm actually using `skip_while(F)` and depend on the fact that if the predicate is false, nothing is consumed. I guess I could make things peekable first?

Comment: Is it possible your solution is a simple for loop with `next()` and `break`? Sometimes the simplest solutions can be the best, and that goes double in a lower level language like Rust

Comment: I did try a `loop`, but it was slower than using `skip_while` for some reason. Maybe I should try again, though...

Comment: I dropped the iterator entirely and did a `for` loop over the slice directly, keeping track of indices myself. This seems to work well and be performant :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think @Silvio's answer is a better perspective.

---

You may call `skip(0)` instead of the `iter` itself in `else` branch...

And the return value of the iterator generated by `enumerate` doesn't match your definition: `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, T)>`. You need to map it.

Here is a working example:

```
use num::Float;

struct CrossingIter<'a, T> {
    index: usize,
    iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
}

impl<'a, T: Float> Iterator for CrossingIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = (usize, T);


    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, T)> {
        let iter = (&mut self.iter).enumerate();
         
        let mut iter = if self.index == 0 {
            self.index += 3;
            iter.skip(3)
        } else {
            iter.skip(0)
        };

        // lots of code here working with the new iterator        

        iter.next().map(|(i, &v)| (i, v))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using `skip_while(F)` and if I have two different `F`'s I get different types again...